# com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Ledu/hawhamburg/vuforia/BuildConfig;

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, dex

An Android project I've been working on for the better part of the last year doesn't work ever since I've bought a new laptop, and I just don't know what to do anymore.

The project itself contains of five subprojects that get included with a *settings.gradle* file.

```
Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Ledu/hawhamburg/vuforia/BuildConfig;
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Ledu/hawhamburg/vuforia/BuildConfig;
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:661)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:616)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:598)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:198)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:61)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:36)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Ledu/hawhamburg/vuforia/BuildConfig;
BUILD FAILED in 12s
15 errors
0 warnings
```

Things I've tried: Updating Gradle, updating Android Studio, clean project, re-clone gitlab project, delete Gradle cache, and also this:

```
android {
    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
    }
}
```

If explicitly disabling pre-dexing doesn't prevent the DexException from appearing, something is seriously screwed up. I just don't know how to find the cause.

Again, this worked on my old computer just fine, so whatever it is, it has to be related to the environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I thing that your project have some Android libraries? If yes, all `AndroidManifest.xml` file must have different `package` attribute in `manifest` tag.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="<<DIFFERENT VALUE HERE>>">
    <application>
...
```

By the way, after changing this, you have to manually delete the `build` directory of the library. `clean` doesn't delete old `BuildConfig` file.

Comment: Which file is this?

Comment: AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: OH MY GOD, IT WORKED! Thank you so much. I've got no idea why this duplicated package name wasn't a problem before I got my new laptop, but that was the problem.